# How to use powerset function in finding the sum of subsets

Tags: scheme, racket

For this problem, I have a function known as powerset function

```
(define (powerset set)
  (if (null? set)
      '(())
      (let ((rest (powerset (cdr set))))
        (append (map (lambda (element) (cons (car set) element))
                     rest)
                rest))))
```

I want to use that function to return true if a subset produced from the powerset function has the sum is equal to the sum passed in as a parameter. I think I got the right idea but im not sure how to implement. I know that the list produced by this function should be passed onto another function 1 subset at a time. In that function i want to add those values in the subset together and see if they are equal to the sum. So far got this but i know its wrong.

```
(define (group list sum)
 (cond((null? list) #f)
      ((equal? (apply + (powerset list)) sum)#t)
      (else (group((powerset list))sum)) ))
```

So I need a function that calls powerset once and passes the lists one at a time onto another function that compares the sum of the subset to my value being passed as sum.

For example if i call:

```
(group '(1 2 4 5) 9)
```

I want that to return #t because the subset (4, 5) summed is equal to 9. If you know how to use powerset and can show an example in solving this problem it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to map a sum function over your list of subsets, which would give you a list whose elements correspond to the sums of each subset. Then you can check if any of elements of this list of sums is equal to the provided target sum.

One way to do this is like so: first we need a function to sum a list. We can use a fold for that:

```
(define (sum set)
    (fold-right + 0 set))
```

Now, we define a function which will return true if a given element is contained in the provided list, and false otherwise:

```
(define (contains n set)
    (if (null? set)
        #f
        (if (= (car set) n)
            #t
            (contains n (cdr set)))))
```

(I'm not an expert at Scheme so I'm not sure if this is something built in).

With this defined, we can write the function you want:

```
(define (group set n)
    (contains n (map sum (powerset set))))
```

You can test that your example `(group '(1 2 4 5) 9)` gives us `#t`.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the input, I tried to attempt to run this, in R5RS language in Dr. Racket, although I am getting errors, it is telling me that fold-right: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

Comment: If you have any idea or could help I would really appreciate it

Comment: Hey actually i just changed the function to a different way of implementing summing those in a list, THANK YOU SO MUCH it works :)